# How to reset back to default css after adding style?

Tags: java, javafx

Basically I have changed the css for a text field in javafx by adding a style class like this:

```
textfield.getStyleClass().add("textfieldstyle");
```

But then I want to be able to revert it back to its original appearance. But since  the original appearance in this case is the default skin for JavaFX, I can't find the original layout for the textfields. I found the textfieldskin properties [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextFieldSkin.java), but its a jungle, and I can't find anything about the color of the -fx-control-inner-background, -fx-text-box-border and -fx-focus-color, which is what I want to know.

I've tried`textfield.getStyleClass().remove("textfieldstyle");` and think that does remove the new css, but it doesn't apply the old one again.

Comment: After removing the styleclass, System.out.println(textfield.getStyleClass()); to be sure. Since you may have added it more than once.

Comment: Is it version 2 or 8 of JavaFX?

Comment: or you can use   `textField.getStyleClass().clear();                textField.getStyleClass().add("text-field");                textField.getStyleClass().add("text-input");` Here is demo https://gist.github.com/varren/3872d5611a2726271be4

Comment: @UlukBiy It's JavaFx 8.

Comment: @Uluk Biy Thanks you just solved me a week long bug... Why the heck isn't the styleclass list, an unique one? q_q

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to the comments by @UlukBiy and @varren I solved the issue. `System.out.println(textfield.getStyleClass());` was of great use since it allowed me to check which style classes were applied on the text field as default. And as it is pointed out in the comments those where `text-input` and `text-field`.

So to restore the text field's css to its default value I just did:

```
textfield.getStyleClass().clear();
textfield.getStyleClass().addAll("text-field", "text-input");
```

Comment: Directly setting the classes works too :

`textfield.getStyleClass().setAll("text-field", "text-input");`

Answer (score 11):

To reset an element's default styling after setting it using `.setStyle("css settings.....");` you can simply use -

```
textfield.setStyle(null);
```

I'm not sure if this would work on it's own for an element that's had a class applied using `.getStyleClass().add("textfieldstyle");` but if not you could do something like -

```
textfield.getStyleClass().clear();
textfield.setStyle(null);
```

Answer (score 7):

A short way to effictively remove your style class even in case of duplicates, with a lambda :

```
textfield.getStyleClass().removeIf(style -> style.equals("textfieldstyle"));
```

Comment: Best one! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The following test code works for me when adding and removing a class from a control such as Textfield:

```
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl;

public class test
{
  protected void setEditable(final TextInputControl toControl, final boolean tlEditable)
  {
    toControl.setEditable(tlEditable);
    if (tlEditable)
    {
      if (toControl.getStyleClass().contains("non-editable-class"))
      {
        toControl.getStyleClass().removeAll("non-editable-class");
      }
    }
    else if (!toControl.getStyleClass().contains("non-editable-class"))
    {
      toControl.getStyleClass().add("non-editable-class");
    }
  }
}
```